# remove border that appears when clicking button

Tags: angular, typescript, border, rating

I have a rating form in which when I click on a star, the following border appears:

[image: rating-form]

implement the following example: [angular-material-star-rating](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-star-rating?file=app%2Fstar-rating%2Fstar-rating.component.ts)

How can I remove this border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the default focus, use the following code:

```
:focus {
   outline:none;
}
```

You can then control the focus border color either individually by element

```
:focus {
   outline:none;
    border:1px solid red
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this rule to the element

```
outline: none
```

Comment: I line I was looking for, thanks.